# iterm2 jump mark in screen or tmux

Tags: screen, tmux, iterm2, iterm

I found set mark (cmd-shift-m) and jump to mark (cmd-shift-j) don't work in screen or tmux, when multiple sessions are opened.

If there is no status bar and you set a mark m1 in session1, and then mark m2 in session2, you will always jump to m2 even if you are in session1.

If there is a status bar (e.g., set by `hardstatus alwayslastline` in screen), then jump to mark doesn't work at all.

Can you test on your machine?